# Cannot open eclipse on ubuntu after re-installing Java JDK

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, ubuntu

After re-installing Java JDK, I cannot open eclipse even if I tried to re-install it as well. I get an error window and was pointed to a log file shown below:

```
!SESSION 2014-06-02 13:40:12.366 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=I20110613-1736
java.version=1.8.0_05
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2014-06-02 13:40:13.457
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load SWT library. Reasons:
        no swt-gtk-3740 in java.library.path
        no swt-gtk in java.library.path
        Can't load library: /home/junfu/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/libswt-gtk-3740.so
        Can't load library: /home/junfu/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/libswt-gtk.so

        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:285)
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:194)
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.C.<clinit>(C.java:21)
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Converter.wcsToMbcs(Converter.java:63)
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Converter.wcsToMbcs(Converter.java:54)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:132)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createDisplay(Workbench.java:695)
        at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createDisplay(PlatformUI.java:161)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.createDisplay(IDEApplication.java:153)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:95)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1386)
```

I tried to find answers with google and I've added the following 2 lines to my eclipse.ini file. But it did not help.

```
-vm
/opt/sun-jdk-1.6.0.02/bin/java
```

Answer (score 0):

For a 64 bit JVM you need a 64 bit Eclipse.

For a 32 bit JVM you need a 32 bit Eclipse.

Download the Eclipse flavor corresponding to your Java flavor.